# a limit of a complex function of $\zeta(s)\zeta(s+1)\Gamma(s)$

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$f(s) = \zeta(s)\zeta(s+1)\Gamma(s) $$

This has a double pole at $s=0$ , from $\zeta(s+1)$ and $\Gamma(s)$ respectively, and $\lim_{s\to0}s^2f(s) = -1/2$

Then, the next step,  I have difficulty with understanding the following (from my book without any explanation)

$$ \lim_{s\to0} s\left(f(s) - \frac{-1/2}{s^2}\right) = -\log\sqrt{2\pi} \;(= \zeta'(0)) $$

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: You can try using $s^2 f(s) =  - \frac{1}{2} + \left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}(t^2 f(t))}}{{{\rm d}t}}} \right]_{t = 0} s + o(s^2 )$ which follows from Taylor's formula.

Comment: @Gary   Thank you. As you said, the key is the value of $\left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}(t^2 f(t))}}{{{\rm d}t}}} \right]_{t = 0}$. But I can't find it because, no matter how I tried,  there still remains $\zeta(1)$ term. Can't get rid of $\zeta(1)$

Comment: @Gary   Can you show me more in details how to get $\left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}(t^2 f(t))}}{{{\rm d}t}}} \right]_{t = 0}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, observe that
$$
\frac{{{\rm d}(t^2 f(t))}}{{{\rm d}t}}  = t^2 f(t)\frac{{{\rm d}\log (t^2 f(t))}}{{{\rm d}t}} = t^2 f(t)\left( {\frac{2}{t} + \frac{{\zeta '(t)}}{{\zeta (t)}} + \frac{{\zeta '(t + 1)}}{{\zeta (t + 1)}} + \frac{{\Gamma '(t)}}{{\Gamma (t)}}} \right).
$$
Utilising the Laurent series expansions of the zeta and gamma functions, we obtain
$$
\frac{{\zeta '(t + 1)}}{{\zeta (t + 1)}} =  - \frac{1}{t} + \gamma  + o(1),\quad \frac{{\Gamma '(t)}}{{\Gamma (t)}} =  - \frac{1}{t} - \gamma  + o(1)
$$
as $t\to0$. Taking into account that
$$
\lim _{t \to 0} t^2 f(t) =  - \frac{1}{2},\quad \frac{{\zeta '(0)}}{{\zeta (0)}} =  - 2\zeta '(0) = 2\log \sqrt {2\pi } ,
$$
we arrive at the desired result.

Comment: WOW. THANK YOU SO MUCH! I had no idea of Laurent series expansions above. I should've studied it more. :)